# asp.net mvc c# getting the url of the page coming from

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i had a form in which i want a url of the page from which it got there. Like i am on /Content/Form and i got there from /Content/Document( i want to save this in my database) . what is the best way for this scenario?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer`

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to simply pass this information to the controller action.

So for example you could include the request url as a hidden field:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Process", "SomeController")) { %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("requestUrl", Request.RawUrl) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

and inside the corresponding controller action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(string requestUrl)
{
    // requestUrl will contain the url of the page used to 
    // render the form
    ...
}
```

You could also use the controller and action from route data:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Process", "SomeController")) { %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("controllerName", ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")) %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("actionName", ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

and both `controllerName` and `actionName` will be sent in the POST request.